# Windows Server 2008 Event ID 1 Kernel-General .... time sync?

Tags: windows-server-2008, ntp

Recently noticed that every once in a while only our 2008 servers log this event ID and adjust the time usually 3 or 4 seconds.  What is this and why have I never noticed before?  They are all set to sync off of one of our domain controllers.  I've run w32tm and net time and everything looks good so I am at a loss as to why this is happening.  Any help is greatly appreciated.

Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

I don't know why you have never noticed it before, but Kernel-General event ID 1 occurs whenever Windows changes the system time, regardless of whether it's a virtual machine or not. Windows changes the system time whenever it detects that the authoritative time, whether that be an NTP server or a Hyper-V host with Time Sync Integration Service, differs from the system clock on that server.

If your clock changes by 3 or 4 seconds on a regular basis, that means your clock is not very good and so it needs correcting often. This is definitely a common problem with virtual machines, but can happen on physical machines too with poor or failing CMOS clocks.

The Hyper-V time sync service takes priority over traditional NTP Windows Time Service settings. Even if the command `w32tm /query /peers` shows that you're set to sync from a domain controller, look in your logs for `Time-Service` events and you will see that the guest OS ends up syncing with the VM IC Time Sync Provider, even after receiving valid NTP data from the network. [I've also experienced problems with Windows perfmon counters when a guest is configured to sync time with a VMware host.](http://www.myotherpcisacloud.com/post/2012/10/06/Mystery-of-the-Performance-Counters-with-Negative-Denominators!.aspx)

I actually prefer traditional NTP service when I have a reliable hardware NTP time service to sync with (or even ntp.org if business policies allow syncing with internet sources.) So if I had to choose one over the other, I would disable the integration service rather than disabling Windows Time service on the  guest OS.

Answer (score 0):

Is this a VM running in Hyper-V?  Are you using the *Time Synchronization* integration service offered by Hyper-V?  If so, disable it and see if they go away.

Comment: Note: Disabling time sync is *usually* a bad idea; though there are several exceptions to that generalization. If this is a VM, his w32tm service should be disabled, not the VM time sync.